# Iterate through variables in a struct c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I need a struct that can hold 3 coordinates as separate variables, but I also need a way to iterate through them. For now, I am doing it like this:

```
struct Vector3
{
    float coords[3];
    float& x = coords[0];
    float& y = coords[1];
    float& z = coords[2];
};
```

This way I can access each individual variable as well as iterate through all of them using the coords array. Problem is: this is very unefficient, both in memory usage and in performance cost. Is there a better solution?

Comment: "_Problem is: this is very unefficient, both in memory usage and in performance cost._" Why do you think so?

Comment: I think you should describe the problem you are trying to solve. Anybody could think _why don't you use `std::array<float,3>` instead of this `Vector3` thing?_

Comment: So make getters that return those references, instead of storing them as members

Comment: @underscore_d I've elaborated your suggestion into an answer, below.

Comment: @Persixty Neat, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As suggest (by underscore_d) in a comment the preferred way is to provide accessor functions.
On any realistic compiler they'll be optimised away so no space or performance issue.

```
struct Vector3 {
    float coords[3];
    float& x() { return coords[0]; }
    float& y() { return coords[1]; }
    float& z() { return coords[2]; }
    
    float x() const { return coords[0]; } 
    float y() const { return coords[1]; }
    float z() const { return coords[2]; }
    
};
```

Here's a little program that gives it a run out.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector3 {
    float coords[3];
    float& x() { return coords[0]; }
    float& y() { return coords[1]; }
    float& z() { return coords[2]; }
    
    float x() const { return coords[0]; } 
    float y() const { return coords[1]; }
    float z() const { return coords[2]; }
    
};

void dump(const std::string& title,const Vector3& v3){
    std::cout << title << '\n';
    std::cout << "{ " << v3.coords[0] << " , " << v3.coords[1] << " , " << v3.coords[2] << " }\n";
    std::cout << "x=" << v3.x() << " y=" << v3.y() << " z=" << v3.z() << '\n' << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Vector3 v3{};
    
    dump("v3 0:",v3);
    
    v3.x()=7.0f;
    v3.y()=3.141f;
    v3.z()=276.0f;
    
    dump("v3 1:", v3);
    
    Vector3 v3c{};
    
    dump("v3 c 0:", v3c);
    v3c=v3;
    dump("v3 c 1:",v3c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Don't overlook that the assignment `v3c=v3` now works 'out of the box'. **Bonus!**
The references broke the default assignment operator. References can't be assigned to be references to other things (in this case the coordinate in the other object - as C++ sees it).

I've provided two sets of getters - `const` and non-`const` - you may not be managing const-ness.

You mention iteration. If you this to the structure definition:

```
const float * begin() const { return coords;}
const float * end() const { return coords + 3; /* Yes 3 */}
float * begin() { return coords;}
float * end() { return coords + 3; /* Yes 3 */}
```

You can use C++ ranged-for loops : `for(auto curr : vec )` as well.
This snippet sets all the coords of `v3` to 7.0.

```
for(auto& curr : v3){
    curr=7.0f;
}
```

I also recommend adding a constructor: `Vector3():coords{} {}` to the struct to initialise all the coordinates to zero. It has a tiny overhead but experience shows its usually the best to avoid 'weird' bugs down the line.

The modern recommendation is to prefer `double` over `float` unless you have good reason. I at least recommend creating a master `typedef float float_type;` and using that consistently in your code. It won't save you any re-engineering but it will reduce the rework if you change take. Also observe "almost always `auto`".
`constexpr float_type zero{0};` may also help.

Expected program output:

```
v3 0:
{ 0 , 0 , 0 }
x=0 y=0 z=0

v3 1:
{ 7 , 3.141 , 276 }
x=7 y=3.141 z=276

v3 c 0:
{ 0 , 0 , 0 }
x=0 y=0 z=0

v3 c 1:
{ 7 , 3.141 , 276 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Iterate through variables in a struct c++

There is no standard way to do this.

You could for example implement a custom iterator to do this. However, for random access, an array is likely to produce efficient code.

> This way I can access each individual variable as well as iterate through all of them using the coords array. Problem is: this is very unefficient

You don't need the references to access individual elements. This works just fine:

```
struct Vector3
{
    float coords[3];
} v;

v.coords[0] = 42; // access first element
```